# cancel incoming call when the caller stop it

Tags: ios, swift, callkit

I want to stop callkit notification in incoming call after the caller is canceled and the receiver has not answered yet so I received that the user canceled the call by another pushkit notification that has a missingCall key.
the problem is that the first try to cancel a call from the caller is a success and the callkit notification is stopped but after that, any call is not canceled until I terminate the app totally and the same thing happen only first-time success

this is the code

```
func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    print("didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload")
    
    let payloadDictionary = payload.dictionaryPayload as NSDictionary
    callOption.callData = payloadDictionary.value(forKey: "aps") as! [String : Any]
    let user = callOption.callData["user"] as! [String  : Any]
    let callerID = user["name"] as! String
    let hasVideo  = true 
    let callUpdate = CXCallUpdate()
    let uuid = UUID()
    callUpdate.remoteHandle = CXHandle(type: .generic, value: callerID)
    callUpdate.hasVideo = hasVideo
          DispatchQueue.global().async {
        self.callOption.ringingApi(otherId: self.callOption.callData["snd_id"] as! String)
    }

    let backgroundTaskIdentifier = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: nil)
    if callOption.callData["typeCall"] as! String == "missingCall" {
        self.endIncomingCall(userId: callOption.callData["snd_id"] as! String)
        UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(backgroundTaskIdentifier)
        
    }
    else {
        self.displayIncomingCall(uuid: uuid, handle: callerID, hasVideo: hasVideo, userId: callOption.callData["snd_id"] as! String) { _ in
                       UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(backgroundTaskIdentifier)
                   }
    }

}
```

here the functions that called above

```
 func displayIncomingCall(uuid: UUID, handle: String, hasVideo: Bool, userId: String, completion: ((NSError?) -> Void)? = nil) {
    providerDelegate?.reportIncomingCall(uuid: uuid, handle: handle, hasVideo: hasVideo, userId: userId, completion: completion)
    }
func endIncomingCall( userId: String) {
    providerDelegate?.reportTheCallerEndCall( userId: userId)
    }
```

and this is the provider delegate

```
 /// Use CXProvider to report the incoming call to the system
func reportIncomingCall(uuid: UUID, handle: String, hasVideo: Bool, userId: String, completion: ((NSError?) -> Void)? = nil) {
       // Construct a CXCallUpdate describing the incoming call, including the caller.
       let update = CXCallUpdate()
       update.remoteHandle = CXHandle(type: .phoneNumber, value: handle)
       update.hasVideo = hasVideo
       provider.reportNewIncomingCall(with: uuid, update: update) { error in
       
           if error == nil {
               let call = Call(uuid: uuid, handle: handle, userId: userId)
               

               self.callManager.add(call: call)
           }
           
           completion?(error as NSError?)
       }
   }

func reportTheCallerEndCall(userId: String) {
    guard let callIndex = self.callManager.findCallIndexInCallsArray(userId: userId) else { return}
    provider.reportCall(with: self.callManager.calls[callIndex].uuid, endedAt: nil, reason: .unanswered)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see at least two problems in your code.

1. You don't need to use a background task to handle the incoming call, it's all handled automatically by the `PushKit` and `CallKit` frameworks.
2. You don't call the `completion` handler of the `pushRegistry(_:didReceiveIncomingPushWith:for:completion:)` function. As you may know, when you receive a VoIP push you must report a new incoming call, otherwise the system won't deliver you any other VoIP push in the future. Given that you don't call the push `completion` handler inside the completion of the `reportNewIncomingCall` function, the system will think that you failed to report the call even if you do it anyway.

```
self.displayIncomingCall(uuid: uuid, handle: callerID, hasVideo: hasVideo, userId: callOption.callData["snd_id"] as! String, completion: completion)
```

Remove the background task start/end and pass the PushKit completion to the incoming call completion.

Comment: thanks for your answer i remove background task and I add completion as the following  self.displayIncomingCall(uuid: uuid, handle: callerID, hasVideo: hasVideo, userId: callOption.callData["snd_id"] as! String) { _ in
                     completion()
                       }.    not solve the problem.  @Marco